# See the following list of errors: Invalid Region/State "WO" in the Row #2.error in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to set shipping charges for UK state wise. e.g. for London 49 euro, scotland 89 euro etc. i have insert the UK's state/region into database.

[Here is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6RkO.png)

Here is the sample of [tablesrates.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf5hn.png)

When i am trying to import the CSV file getting error
`"File has not been imported. See the following list of errors: Invalid Region/State "WO" in the Row #2."`

Please help me. Where i am doing wrong. I have try all solutions but doesn't work.
Thanks...

Comment: Have you confirmed that there is no additional space or any special character in Region column in csv file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?